# Classifying of hand gestures using HMMs on Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm currently working on a project where I should classify hand gestures, many papers proposed that HMMs is the way to do so, many tutorials speak of either a weather tutorial or a dice and coin tutorial, I can't seem to understand how to map these to my problem and what should my different matrices be, I currently have a feature vector (containing the detected features of the hands as a n*2 matrix where n is the total number of features detected in all the frames, i.e. if the algorithm detected 10 features in each frame and the video is 10 frames, n would be = 100, and 2 is the x and y coordinates) and the motion vector (the motion of the hand itself in the video m*2 size where m is the number of frames in the video) also any other data u would recommend to extract from the video.

Answer (score 2):

I know the papers you are talking about and the exemples about the weather are simplistic and cannot be mapped to most of the problems now processed with HMMs. In your case, you have features corresponding to hand gestures that you know. HMM can work because the data you have is dynamic, i.e. ordered in time.

My advice is that you should first have a look at the widely used HMM toolbox by Kevin Murphy. It provides all the tools you need to start working with HMMs.
The main idea is to model each gesture type with one dedicated HMM. For a given gesture type, the corresponding HMM will be trained with the available features that you have.

Once trained, you get a state transition probability matrix, an emission probability matrix and a prior for selecting the initial state.

When your have an unknown gesture, you will then compute the likelihood this gesture (its features actually) could have been generated by each of the trained HMMs. Usually, the query sequence is assigned to the category of the one raising the highest score.

This is for the big picture. In your case, you will have to find a way to represent your features as a time series. The "time" being the different frames. With a complex application such as hand gesture it might be difficult to see what each state of the model represents. Some kinds of HMM, by their topology (left-to-right models for instance) make this analogy easier.

Comment: how to train an HMM using murphy's tool box !

Comment: [http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Software/HMM/hmm_usage.html](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Software/HMM/hmm_usage.html) This is the "How to use" manual. I find it pretty clear about how to train a basic HMM. Hope it helps!